# What is a one word synonym for "Not Yet Started"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am making categories and subcategories in a folder and I am trying to keep the tags to one word if possible. "Unstarted" is all I can find online and it just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Pending, sounds about right. :)

Comment: *Pending* defines something that is awaiting decision  rather than something that has not yet begun.

Comment: @TowerofTesla - Try looking up more than one on-line dictionary. Merriam Webster uses "while waiting for". Consider "Once written, the manager or clerk must enter it into the work order log, file one copy into the pending work order file, and deliver the other copy to the craftsperson." from https://books.google.com/books?id=vNelZl3M1TIC&pg=PA41&dq=%22pending%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAjgyahUKEwi9-ff_yqfIAhVDOT4KHbQIBMw#v=onepage&q=%22pending%22&f=false  The "pending work order file" is exactly the sort of thing the poster has in mind.

Comment: Merriam's full definition of *pending* is "while awaiting <pending approval>". This seems to me to be referring to something that has already been **started**, completed, and is only awaiting confirmation.

Comment: That's only one example. Something "pending" could be awaiting anything, not just approval.

Comment: "*Pending Commencement*" ... I like it

Answer (score 12):

If I've interpreted correctly, you want a word describing something that you have decided on, but not yet started. Per Collins Dictionary:

> **[Unbegun](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unbegun)**: not commenced; not yet started; not having a beginning; always existing.

Comment: Or perhaps more commonly- *unstarted*

Answer (score 4):

Unstarted/Unbegun all mean that you have not started to work on tasks you have in mind. However, once they are in your folder, that means you've already started to work on them by putting them in that category and they must be either finished or discarded in the future.

The 3 biggest categories for all tasks will be "something to start (it can be sub-categorized depending on priority/importance)", "work-in-progress (it can be sub-categorized depending on progress/priority)", and "finished or pending final approval".

"[**To-do-list**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to-do-list)" means according to Oxford Dictionary;

> A list of tasks that need to be completed, typically organized in
>   order of priority:

"[**Ideas**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idea)"" might be considered for the category as it just means what is in your thought or you have come up with recently.

I would go for "To-do-list".

Todoist is a popular application which helps organize your tasks. I find this name simple and clear.

Comment: I quite like this answer. It is more correct than my own.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple ways to say it, not as one word, but as  an *idiom*:

- **in the hopper**
  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+hopper
- **on deck**
  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+deck

But for a short tag on a folder, you could use an *acronym* such as

- **TBD**  (To Be Determined/Done)
- **TBA** (To Be Arranged), that is, the *time* to start the work has yet to be arranged)